# NET::ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID after manual renewal with certbot

Tags: ssl, nginx, certbot

My [website](https://startuplab.io/) keeps getting "NET::ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID" error.

I have renewed the certificate using:

```
sudo certbot certonly --webroot -w /var/www/html  -d startuplab.io
```

and have restarted nginx.

It used to work fine before, my other websites work fine as well.

How do I figure out what went wrong?

Edit:

This [tool](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=startuplab.io&latest) shows me that certificate expired 21 days ago.

Letsencrypt tells me:

> Congratulations! Your certificate and chain have been saved at
>   /etc/letsencrypt/live/startuplab.io-0001/fullchain.pem. Your cert
>   will expire on 2019-05-22. To obtain a new or tweaked version of
>   this certificate in the future, simply run certbot again. To
>   non-interactively renew *all* of your certificates, run "certbot
>   renew"

Edit 2:

Aha! My `ssl-startuplab.io.conf` snippet points to

`ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/startuplab.io/fullchain.pem;`

but certbot has put it into

`ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/startuplab.io-0001/fullchain.pem;`

Does anybody know why this happens? What should I do to fix this and avoid it in the future?

Edit 3:

Just renaming the `startuplab.io-0001` folder into `startuplab.io` fixed the issue. But why did this happen to begin with? How do I make sure it never happens again? I'd appreciate any advice!

Answer (score 0):

For your edit 3, from https://certbot.eff.org/docs/using.html#renewing-certificates emphasis added:

> An alternative form that provides for more fine-grained control over the renewal process (while renewing specified certificates one at a time), is `certbot certonly` **with the complete set of subject domains of a specific certificate specified via `-d` flags**. ...
>
> All of the domains covered by the certificate must be specified in this case in order to renew and replace the old certificate rather than obtaining a new one; don’t forget any `www.` domains! **Specifying a subset of the domains creates a new, separate certificate** containing only those domains, rather than replacing the original certificate. When run with a set of domains corresponding to an existing certificate, the certonly command attempts to renew that specific certificate.

[Your old cert](https://crt.sh/?id=912753858) was for `startuplab.io` AND `webacademy.io` -- not only the former.